# Replacing \n or \r\n with <br /> in javascript by using variables

Tags: javascript, variables, replace, escaping, literals

I am passing 2 variables to javascript function,

1. ReplaceTo = `\n/g`

and

2. ReplaceWith = `<br />`

Below is the sample input string, desired output and current code I am using, but it does not replace anything.

Input String:  `Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n`

Desired Output String: `Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/>Line 3<br/>`

```js
var inputStr = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n";
var ReplaceTo = "\n/g" ;
var ReplaceWith = "<br />";
inputStr = inputStr.replace(ReplaceTo, ReplaceWith);
```

I know that if I hard-code in the replace function like `.replace(/\\n/g, <br />)` it will work, but I need to use variables as I am passing values from config.

Can some one please help how to replace using variables with these special characters.

Comment: `var ReplaceTo = /\n/g ;` <-- that is how the reg exp should be

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceTo must be a regex, not an string. Here the working code

```js
var inputStr = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n";

var inputReplace = new RegExp("\\n", 'g')

var ReplaceWith = "<br />";
inputStr = inputStr.replace(inputReplace, ReplaceWith);
console.log(inputStr)
```

Comment: but replaceTo is a string coming from config, how can I convert that variable into regex.

Comment: @user3112886 Then you need to create a RegExp variable. Look at the edited answer

Comment: if I have "\r\n" coming from config and passed as a variable, how can I create RegExp for it ?     e.g. var replaceTo = new RegExp('\\' + ruleValues.trim(), 'g'); where ruleValues = "\r\n"  , only \n works now. But I need to use \r\n as well. my output regex should be -  /\\r\\n